# Where can I locate exact credentials for MySQL Database PHP connection in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

Where can I find the exact credentials to input into my PHP script to connect to a MySQL database. If applicable, where is this information in the latest cPanel or recent PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Your hosting provider should have given you this information in some way. It doesn't have to be hardcoded in either product.

Comment: My hosting provider didn't, do you know if I can find this information in cPanel or PHPMyAdmin? @Pekka 웃

Comment: In phpMyAdmin - it depends how it's set up, but you can check out the `config.inc.php` file whether it's hardcoded there.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the cPanel go to MySQL Databases section.
2. And then scroll down to the Add New User Section and add a new user.
3. Then scroll down to the Add User To the Database section and add your created user to the Database.
4. Give the user all the privileges that you want it to have.
5. Enjoy!